# How to add a custom button besides Edit & Remove in campaign member

Tags: custom-button

How to add a custom button besides Edit & Remove in campaign member[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is native Salesforce section, so its not possible unless you override complete campaign detail page with a VF page. Which I would not recommend.